# How to overlay/downmix two audio files using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, cmd

Can I overlay/downmix two audio mp3 files into one mp3 output file using ffmpeg?

Comment: You can decode both of them, mix ([pretty simple operation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567156/453271)) and encode again

Comment: Can you please mention commands to do that. I checked the other post you mentioned in your link but it did not help.

Comment: @Faisalcan u please guide me..how to build ffmpeg on ubuntu? if yes then i will post new question on Stackoverflow with all the necessary details..

Answer (score 177, accepted):

## stereo + stereo → stereo

#### Normal downmix

[image: Normal downmix]

Use the [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -i input1.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.mp3
```

Or the [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -i input1.mp3 -filter_complex amerge=inputs=2 -ac 2 output.mp3
```

#### Downmix each input into specific output channel

[image: Downmix each input into specific output channel]

Use the [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) and [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -i input1.mp3 -filter_complex "amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3" output.mp3
```

---

## mono + mono → stereo

[image: mono + mono → stereo]

Use the [join](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -i input1.mp3 -filter_complex join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo output.mp3
```

Or [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -i input1.mp3 -filter_complex amerge=inputs=2 output.mp3
```

---

## mono + mono → mono

[image: mono + mono → mono]

Use the [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -i input1.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.mp3
```

---

## More info and examples

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)

Comment: Thanks, it really helped and done without errors. But my audio files are different in length. Do you have any idea that how to generate output file to the maximum length of input files?

Comment: please can you give the example by putting fake path and value . It will be appreciated

Comment: Will it be using like this ??
{"ffmpeg","-i", Audio,"-i",Audio2,  "-filter_complex" ,"amerge", "-c:a", "libmp3lame","-q:a","4" ,filenameVideoReplace};

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Your code is not working for Merging two audio files.

Comment: It worked for me. It's perfect and faster

"ffmpeg -y -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3"

Comment: it throws me error in log ***Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'***

Comment: @ArslanAhmad Without your actual command and the complete console output I can only guess that your `ffmpeg` was not configured with `--enable-libmp3lame` and therefore cannot use this encoder.

Comment: `amerge` creates *one multi-channel* which is then "squashed" into a stereo stream by `-ac 2`. @Ehsan's answer utilising `amix` is the better way to go.

Comment: @Hermann amerge is more flexible in this regard because you can choose the desired downmix channel layout, but either should be fine for the general user.

Comment: @llogan, I tried using this cmd but it goes to the failure callback method.

Comment: @AsifSb I don't know what that means.

Comment: @llogan, I tried using this command for merging two audios using FFMPEG, It is not working.If it is working for you can you please share some code?

Comment: @AsifSb Use a pastebin link to show your ffmpeg command and the complete log from the command.

Comment: @AsifSb Is the problem with the script or the ffmpeg command? If the problem is ffmpeg then get rid of the extra layer of complexity from the scripting. Just run the ffmpeg command manually, unscripted and provide the complete log from the ffmpeg command. Once you verify that ffmpeg runs only then should you attempt to script it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the FFmpeg but command. Because when I try to execute another command it gives me success.

Comment: @AsifSb The command works for me. I can't help you because you never provided the log from ffmpeg.

Answer (score 24):

Check this out:

```
ffmpeg -y -i ad_sound/whistle.mp3 -i ad_sound/4s.wav -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame ad_sound/outputnow.mp3
```

I think it will help.

Comment: this worked better for me, as take care of the differences in lenght.. this is how I mixed three sounds: 
ffmpeg -i flute_long.ogg -i gallop.ogg -i wind.ogg -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=3:duration=longest"  main.ogg

Comment: Is there anyway to adjust the volume on one of the input files down say 20%?

Comment: @chovy ffmpeg -y -i A.mp3 -i B.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0]volume=0.2[a];[1:0]volume=0.5[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame output1.mp3

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly for me. I wanted to combine 2 different sound's into 1 file that has different durations.

Comment: Not a good solution.  The volume of one of the audios must be decreased significantly if it is used as backgroumd (most common case). So one has to *actually* modify the volume of that file in order thast if can be mixed. See solution by @Sheetansh Kumar ...

Answer (score 20):

For merging two audio files with **different volumes and different duration** following command will work:

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0]volume=0.09[a];[1:0]volume=1.8[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

Here duration can be change to **longest or to shortest**, you can also change the **volume levels** according to your need.

If you're looking to **add background music to some voice** use the following command as in the **gaps the music will become loud automatically**:

```
ffmpeg -i bgmusic.mp3 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.003:ratio=20[bg]; [bg][mix]amerge[final]" -map [final] final.mp3
```

In this threshold is something whose value will decide how much loud the audio should be, **the less the threshold more the audio will be**. Ratio gives how much the other audio should be compressed, **the more the ratio the more the compression is**.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with my issue: I have 1 audio (length about 1 hour) and 1 background music only 1-3 minutes length. I want background music loop with audio length. How can I do that?

Comment: You can concatenate same audio clip multiple times till the required length and while merging with 1hour clip you selected longest/shortest according to your requirement.

Comment: getting error with amerge 

The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_2
    Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.

Comment: Great solution! Modify the volume on the run and ww/o having to actually lower the volume of one of the audios.  This answer should get the most upvotes!

Comment: Instead of `volume`, `amix` can accept `=weights="0.09 1.8"`

Answer (score 19):

The `amix` filter helps to mix multiple audio inputs into a single output.

If you run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 -i INPUT3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT
```

This command will mix 3 input audio streams (I used two mp3 files, in the example below) into a single output with the same duration as the first input and a dropout transition time of 3 seconds.

The `amix` filter accepts the following parameters:

- **inputs**:
  The number of inputs. If unspecified, it defaults to 2.
- **duration**:
  How to determine the end-of-stream.

  - *longest*:
    The duration of the longest input. (default)
  - *shortest*:
    The duration of the shortest input.
  - *first*:
    The duration of the first input.
- **dropout_transition**:
  The transition time, in seconds, for volume renormalization when an input stream ends. The default value is 2 seconds.

For example, I ran the following command in Ubuntu:
FFMPEG version: 3.2.1-1
UBUNTU 16.04.1

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp3 -i bSound.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 OUTPUT.mp3
```

`-codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0` was used to set a variable bit rate. Remember that, you need to install the libmp3lame library, if is necessary. But, it will work even without the `-codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0` part.

Reference: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix

Comment: Perfect explanation of amix :)

Comment: Works perfectly well AND is also available for avconv, contrary to the amerge plugin which didn't work for my version of avconv `(avconv version 9.20-6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)`

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with my issue: I have 1 audio (length about 1 hour) and 1 background music only 1-3 minutes length. I want background music loop with audio. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If they are different length, you can use [apad](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) to add a silent sound to the shortest one

Answer (score 0):

With Bash

```sh
set 'amovie=a.mp3 [gg]; amovie=b.mp3 [hh]; [gg][hh] amerge'
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "$1" -q 0 c.mp3
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/c309610/scripts/ff-merge-audio.sh)

Comment: Thanks it helped. what if length of both files is different?

Comment: example offline - what exactly does set do with this argument? how does this influence the following `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: @DanielAlder `set` changes the value of `$1`. It's really not needed here; just do `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i 'amovie=a.mp3 [gg]; amovie=b.mp3 [hh]; [gg][hh] amerge' -q 0 c.mp3`. I don't actually think the `-i` should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command arguments:

```
   // Command is here

let commandValue = "-y -i \(recordedAudioPath) -i \(backgroundAudio) -filter_complex [\(0):a][\(1):a]amerge=inputs=\(2)[a] -map [a] -ac \(2) -shortest -preset ultrafast \(outputPath)"
  MobileFFmpeg.execute(commandValue)
```