# Merging two MP3 audio files

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, mixing

I am trying to use ffmpeg library for mixing two MP3 or wav audio files using the commands available that I searched over Internet like given below:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

From link [How to overlay two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14498539)

Also, tried some many other solutions given on the different forms.

But none of them is working for the the library downloaded from link:
https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java.

But when I am trying to run the commands available on the intener, in some commands I am getting different different error like,

```
-- Unable to find suitable output format for 'ffmpeg' ffmpeg: Invalid argument
```

And I also tried one more command,

```
 String res = "ffmpeg -y -i " + a.getAbsolutePath() + " -i " + b.getAbsolutePath() + " -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest' -c:a libmp3lame " + c.getAbsolutePath();
```

It's giving error, `No such filter:" Error configuring filters.`

Comment: HAve you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of FFmpeg?
I believe it's old and that's why it's not working.

First setp download newest version from [official site](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) try if your command it's working if yes than find another (or build your own) compiled for android executable file

Answer (score 0):

Well First check your [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) version. The way you have used the `amix` filter have to be changed. `amix` filter mix audios. So following is what I'm suggesting.

```
ffmpeg -i input_audio1 -i input_audio2 -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=10[s1];
[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];
[0:a][ac1]amix[aout]" -map [aout] -c:a libmp3lame output_audio
```

you can append a silent audio which duration is same as the first audio and them use `amix` over them. So the original audio's will not overlap. [`aevalsrc`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#aevalsrc) will create a silent audio with a duration of 10 sec. Also you need to select appropriate codec for your output accordingly. You can find those codec [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Audio-Encoders).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been some time since this question was posted, but I think your main problem is that you shouldn't include "ffmpeg" on your string.

So your cmd line would be:

```
String res = "-y -i " + a.getAbsolutePath() + " -i " + b.getAbsolutePath() + " -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest' -c:a libmp3lame " + c.getAbsolutePath();
```