# Pipe PCM-Streams into one function

Tags: node.js, audio, stream, pcm

I have two PCM-streams (`decoder1` + `decoder2`):

```
var readable1 = fs.createReadStream("track1.mp3");
var decoder1 = new lame.Decoder({
    channels: 2,
    mode: lame.STEREO
});
readable1.pipe(decoder1);
```

and

```
var readable2 = fs.createReadStream("track2.mp3");
var decoder2 = new lame.Decoder({
    channels: 2,
    mode: lame.STEREO
});
readable2.pipe(decoder2);
```

Now I want to pipe the streams into one mix-function, where I can use the buffer-function like:

```
function mixStream(buf1, buf2, callback) {
    // The mixStream-Function is not implemented yet (dummy)
    var out = new Buffer(buf1.length);
    for (i = 0; i < buf1.length; i+=2) {
        var uint = Math.floor(.5 * buf1.readInt16LE(i));
        out.writeInt16LE(uint, i);
    }

    this.push(out);
    callback();
}
```

I need something like

```
mixStream(decoder1.pipe(), decoder2.pipe(), function() { }).pipe(new Speaker());
```

for output to speaker. Is this possible?

Comment: This is exactly that I'm looking for as well. Did you ever find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `pipe()` function actually means a stream is linked to another, a readable to a writable, for instance. This 'linking' process is to `write()` to the writable stream once any data chunk is ready on the readable stream, along with a little more complex logic like `pause()` and `resume()`, to deal with the `backpressure`.

So all you have to do is to create a pipe-like function, to process two readable streams at the same time, which drains data from stream1 and stream2, and once the data is ready, write them to the destination writable stream.

I'd strongly recommend you to go through Node.js docs for `Stream`.

Hope this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Sorry, I am extremely not very familiar with PCM streams etc. What I don't understand mostly is how to merge the two streams into one output stream -- which I thought this question was asking hence why I put the bounty on it.

Comment: I am not very familiar with PCM but if you are considering merging two streams into one, I'd be glad to provide further help, but maybe you got time for the docs first? BTW, if you are trying to overlay two tracks into a single audio file. I'd recommend this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg . You can simply use child_process to spawn the ffmpeg to do the job.

Comment: I thought I understood streams pretty well but obviously not enough haha. Just as you commented this I was searching up basics for PCM streams in Node.js, hopefully I'll get something out of it.