# How to combine two mp3 files into one that will play simultaneously using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, merge, mp3

I have two mp3 files of the same format (frequency, bitrate, etc) and of the same length. They are called: *drums-track.mp3* and *piano-track.mp3*.

I need to merge these files into one that will play simultaneously. I can't use music programs because I have a lot of such file that to be processed.

I tried to combine them with cat and play it:

```
$ cat drums-track.mp3 > combined.mp3
$ cat piano-track.mp3 >> combined.mp3

$ mpg123 combined.mp3
...
This was a Frankenstein track.
[0:12] Decoding of combined.mp3 finished.
```

It plays not simultaneously but right one after another and tells me that it is a Frankenstein track :)

Comment: `mpg123 drums-track.mp3 & mpg123 piano-track.mp3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlay two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: @D'ArcyNader, thanks a lot! That's exactly what I need.